# How to access slot props in the created hook?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, children

I'm trying to access properties I'm passing on to my slot. But my `slotProps` are undefined.

As I'm still new to Vue and I've read their docs I still can't seem to figure out why I can't access the props data.

**Problem**

I'm trying to access the `slotProps` in my child components `created`, but it's undefined

*emphasized text*

```
<template>
  <div>
    <slot :data="data" :loading="loading"></slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

*Child*

```
<template v-slot:default="slotProps">
  <div >

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "child"
  created: function() {
    console.log("slotProps", slotProps);
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***this*** object to follow with your child property

demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-kkhwzc?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue

Updated code ***Child***

```
<template v-slot:default="slotProps">
  <div >

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "child"
  created: function() {
    console.log("slotProps", this.slotProps);
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You do not need the `created()` life cycle hook to achieve what you want. There are few things to clear up:

- What you are using is actually called [scoped slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots). They are useful because, unlike when using the default and named slots, the parent component can not access the data of its child component(s).
- What you call a ***Child*** is actually the parent component.

**Child.vue** component should be something like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <main>
      <slot :data="data1" :loading="loading1" />
    </main>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Page',
  data () {
    return {
      data1: 'foo',
      loading1: 'bar'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

In a **Parent.vue** component, you can access the data of the above component as follows:

```
<template>
  <child>
    <template v-slot="slotProps">
      {{ slotProps.data }},
      {{ slotProps.loading }}
    </template>
  </child>
</template>

<script>
import Child from '@/components/Child.vue'

export default {
  components: { Child }
}
</script>
```

Or you can also [destruct](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the objects on the fly as follows:

```
<template>
  <child>
    <template v-slot="{data, loading }">
      {{ data }},
      {{ loading }}
    </template>
  </child>
</template>

<script>
import Child from '@/components/Child.vue'

export default {
  components: { Child }
}
</script>
```

This is the clean way to access data of a child component from the parent using scoped slots.

Comment: Okay so _how_ to access say `slotProps.data` in the `Parent.vue`'s JavaScript code (as opposed to in its template)? So far your answer does not say it.